# É possivel HashMap com varios valores?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

Eu preciso preencher um banco assim:

> Leite 50 kcal 20 proteinas 120 carbo etc.

Eu cheguei fazer com *hashmap*, mas só consigo usar um *key* pra um valor, teria como fazer com vários valores, ou outra maneira que possa fazer isso sem ser usando `HashMap`?

```
Map<String, Integer> mapalimentos = new HashMap<>();
    mapalimentos.put("Maçã",60);
    mapalimentos.put("Melancia",75);
    mapalimentos.put("Banana",45);

    //Log.d(TAG, "addalimentosbanco: adicionou");


    for (final Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : mapalimentos.entrySet()) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "addalimentosbanco: Nome: " + entry.getKey() +" Calorias: "+ entry.getValue());
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                Alimento alimento = realm.createObject(Alimento.class);
                alimento.setNome(entry.getKey());
                alimento.setCalorias(entry.getValue());
            }
        });
    }
    RealmResults<Alimento> results = realm.where(Alimento.class).findAll();
    Log.d(TAG, "addalimentosbanco: Result: " + results);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É simples, crie uma classe com os membros que precisa usar, então faça o valor ser este objeto com todos os membros dentro. Algo assim (de forma muito simplificada):

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<String, Alimento> mapalimentos = new HashMap<>();
        mapalimentos.put("Maçã", new Alimento(50, 10));
        mapalimentos.put("Melancia", new Alimento(30, 20));
    }
}

class Alimento {
    public Alimento(int calorias, int proteinas) {
        Calorias = calorias;
        Proteinas = proteinas;
    }
    int Calorias;
    int Proteinas;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yi0JFE). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dydhoewd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/HashMapObject.java).

Não observei se o código tem outros problemas.